# Angular.js with Bootstrap carousel only one nav dot showing up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am trying to integrate Bootstrap Carousel into my Angular app and I am having some issues getting the nav dots to show up for each image and I am also having an issue getting the navigation arrows to move back and forth between slides.

Here is part of my html template with the carousel:

```
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" ng-init="getCars()">

 //////////section for nav dots///////////////

<ol class="carousel-indicators" ng-repeat="car in cars">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="{{$index}}" ng-class="{active:!$index}"></li>
        </ol>

/////////////section for carousel images////////////////////

        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item" ng-class="{active:!$index}" ng-repeat="car in cars">
            <img class="first-slide" src="{{car.picture.url}}" alt="First slide" style="margin:auto">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>{{car.make}} {{car.model}}</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

//////////section for nav arrows///////////////

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
```

The nav dots are not working as only one shows up. The images are automatically cycled through so I no the carousel image section is working to some degree. If I write out the individual `<li>`s for nav dots I am able to swap between the images in the carousel. So something is off with my ng-repeat in that section and it is probably some noob mistake.

As for the arrow function I am not sure how to make those link up with my current set up. Any suggestions there would be great also. One step at a time though first the nav dots. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: You say your learning, have included https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ if you don't things don't work right.

Comment: I tried using ui-bootstrap previously and it gave me some errors. I tried it again since you mentioned it and it gave me the same problem. ui-bootstrap seems like the most logical solution but I have not been able to get it work. I googled the errors again it was giving me and it led me to someone who had the same issue and resolved it by removing ui-bootstrap and using regular bootstrap carousel. Here is the link that helped me resolve it: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3502
Thanks for your help! Sometimes just bouncing ideas off people gets them to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure without seeing the controller but

```
ng-init="getCars()"
```

may need to be

```
ng-init="cars=getCars()"
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea I have defiantly messed up setting up controllers in the past. The controller is setup properly or at least in a functioning manner as it is pulling the cars from the getCars function.